# Clear glassfish Batch Job Executions

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-batch

I'm looking a way to clear each day the glassfish batch log from my java application (via batchlet or ejb timer).

Maybe another way could be to keep only the failed job and purge the success batch, is it possible to do it?

Thanks,
Ersch